# Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Why am I getting this error? I have not been able to find a solution online or through ChatGPT.
It is being flagged on line 14 in the below code `@State isLoggedIn`

> "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs)"

### Full code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct pp: View {
    @Environment (\.modelContext) private var Context
    @Environment (\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Query(sort: \datasoso.id) var profile : [datasoso]
    @State private var username :String = ""
    @State private var email : String = ""
    @State private var password : String = ""
    @State var friends: [String] = []
    @State private var isLoggedIn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if isLoggedIn {
                    // Show the profile page with user information
                    ProfileInfoView()
                } else {
                    // Show the profile page with no information and a sign up button
                    EmptyProfileView()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Profile")
            .toolbar {
                if isLoggedIn {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button(action: {
                            // Log out the user
                        }) {
                            Text("Log Out")
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button(action: {
                            // Sign up the user
                        }) {
                            Spacer
                            Text("Sign vUp")
                                .padding(.bottom)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ProfileInfoView: View {
    // Show the user's profile information, such as name, email, etc.
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink {
            Friends(email: $email, username: $username, friends: $friends)
        } label: {
            Text("friends").foregroundColor(.r)
            
        }
        Spacer()
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Account Information")){
                HStack{                          Text("Email:")
                    Text($email)
                        .font(.body)
                    .padding()}
                HStack{
                    Text("Username:")
                    Text($username)
                        .font(.body)
                    .padding()}
                Button(action: {
                    //logout()
                }) {
                    Text("Logout")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                        .background
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.white)
            }
            
        }.listStyle(.plain)
        Spacer()
    }
}

struct EmptyProfileView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Account Information")){
                    HStack{                          Text("Email:")
                            .font(.body)
                        .padding()}
                    HStack{
                        Text("Username:")
                            .font(.body)
                        .padding()}
                    NavigationLink(destination: signup(), label: "sign up")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                        .background
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.white)
            }
            
        }.listStyle(.plain)
        Spacer()
        
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error? There's another post similar to this, but it doesn't have any answers.

Comment: Comment things out until you find the cause. Line 14 of the code you've shared doesn't correspond to the error. The error has typos in it -- maybe your code does as well? Also, although it doesn't cause the error, it makes it much easier for others (like those on this site) to read the code if you conform to the Swift standard practices for capitalization.

Comment: @jnpdx it works , it was the toolbar but do you know why?... im new in swiftui so ..

Comment: You've got lot's of typos in your code,.`Spacer` should end with `()`. And there's a superfluous bracket at the end of the first `ToolbarItem` in the if clause. But really, there's lot's of other issues in your code.

Comment: The "why" it didn't compile was the bugs in your code (that you appear to have found). The "why" it gave you an unhelpful message was the bugs in the Swift compiler. As the error indicated, they would like you to send them a bug report so they can fix the compiler bug. The Swift compiler still has a lot of trouble providing good errors in complex SwiftUI code that is incorrect. Splitting you code up into smaller pieces will help the compiler give you better errors when you make mistakes.

Comment: @bil: Depending on the iOS version you're using, you're not allowed to use `if` and `else` directly inside `toolbar`. Instead, you might have to refactor your code to move the `if`s inside your `ToolbarItem`s.